# print a ruby array to be used with Highcharts

Tags: ruby, highcharts

I have an array with some query to be used as data in Highcharts

the Ruby array is @report

```
subscriptions.each do |data|
    idx = data['index'].gsub(/-/, '').to_i
    @report['summary'][idx] ||= {}
    @report['summary'][idx]['total_month'] ||= 0
    @report['summary'][idx]['year'] = data['year']
    @report['summary'][idx]['month'] = data['month']
    @report['summary'][idx]['day'] = data['day']
    @report['summary'][idx]['hour'] = data['hour']
    @report['summary'][idx]['total_month'] +=  data['quantity'].to_i
    @report['summary'][idx][data['operator']] = data['quantity']

    @report['total'][data['operator']] += data['quantity'].to_i
    @report['total']['global'] += data['quantity'].to_i
end
```

And the Highchart script is...

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
var chart1 = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'line'
    },
    title: {
        text: <%= @subservice.service.name %>
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Year', 'Month']
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'total'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'total',
        data: <%= @report["total"].to_json %>
    }]
});
})
```

How i can print the @report values??

Comment: You mean print for debugging purposes?

Comment: No i mean to show the values in the graph

Comment: Your question is misleading, please try to be more specific. What exactly is your problem? What have you tried to solve it, so far?